# contain text into svg shape d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have to write some text into SVG shape created with d3.js
I need to limit it inside the shape like in this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582

I tried to use a clipPath like in the example. Exploring with firebug the text seems exist but I can't see it. here's my code:

JS:

```
d3.select(".nodes").selectAll("g").append("clipPath")
   .attr("id", function(d) { return "clip-" + d.id; })
   .append("use")
   .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#" + d.id.; });


d3.select(".nodes").selectAll("g")
   .append("text")
   .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-" + d.id; })
   .attr("style","sans-serif;text-anchor:middle;fill:black;")
   .append("tspan")
   .attr("x", 3)
   .attr("y", 0)
   .attr("font-size","10px")
   .text(function(d) { 
         return d.id
    });
```

and the result in html:

```
 <g transform="translate(631.5288807476019,511.0571103008831)">
   <circle class="none" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="4px" r="20" cursor="pointer">
   <clipPath id="clip-DDD">
    <use href="#DDD">
   </clipPath>
   <text clip-path="url(#clip-DDD)" style="sans-serif;text-anchor:middle;fill:black;">
    <tspan x="3" y="0" font-size="10px">DDD</tspan>
   </text>
</g>
```

Comment: problem fixed, i forgot the attr "id" on the shape XD

Comment: you also might want to remove the '.' after the 'd.id'  in the two places where it appears above (it may or may not cause you issues, but it through an error when I made the codepen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the use 'href' attr needs to match the id of your circle element (in Bostock's example you can see that the 'href' attributes of his use elements match the rect id that he wants to fill)

I think you code would work if you added an id to the circle element like this:

```
<circle id="DDD" class="none" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="4px" r="20" cursor="pointer">
```

Here is a link to a codepen that models this as much as I can with the code you showed me: http://codepen.io/haydenwagner/pen/LxbLgd

As you can see the text does show up in the clip-path and the circle element has an ID that matches the use elements 'href' attribute.